# swap back caps and ctrl

Tags: windows, keyboard, emacs, remapping

I used to use swapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps</kbd> for editing files in Emacs under Windows XP, so I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> function bind to <kbd>Caps</kbd>. Now I've got a new machine, and old traveled to another man, who wants to have native bindings.  Is there a way to swap them back?

Comment: When giving a computer to someone else, you should erase all personal information.  With Windows, that means a complete reinstallation.  That also eliminates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is, run regedit, navigate to the following registry directory:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout

and delete the Scancode Map, which, if all you've done is flip the Ctrl-L and Caps-Lock keys, should have the following value:

00000000 00000000 03000000 3A001D00 1D003A00 00000000

CAUTION: deleting the scancode map will also delete any other key mappings you've created.  For a better understanding of how the Scancode Map works, consult MSDN's article on its scan code mapper:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A safe way to remap your keys is to use a program like [KeyTweak](http://www.tucows.com/preview/327616).  It does the registry work for you.